Path traversal in webpack-dev-middleware - CVE-2024-29180
The Dependabot (https://github.com/jianmingtu/test-ai-reviewer/security/dependabot/11) alerts the error "Path traversal in webpack-dev-middleware - CVE-2024-29180".
Given this dependency chain, updating to a secure version seems non-trivial. Here’s more detail on the vulnerability:
webpack-dev-middleware:
Affected versions: <= 5.3.3
Patched version: 5.3.4
Questions:
   How do I fix it in package.json ?  I wants to add packages and versions in the resolutions section.  I tried this but it does not work:

      "resolutions": {
        "webpack-dev-server": "4.15.2",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.3.4"
     } 

$yarn list  shows webpack-dev-middleware at two places as below:
   ├─ webpack-dev-server@4.11.1
    │  ├─ @types/bonjour@^3.5.9
    │  ├─ @types/connect-history-api-fallback@^1.3.5
    │  ├─ @types/express@^4.17.13
    │  ├─ @types/serve-index@^1.9.1
    │  ├─ @types/serve-static@^1.13.10
    │  ├─ @types/sockjs@^0.3.33
    │  ├─ @types/ws@^8.5.1
    │  ├─ ansi-html-community@^0.0.8
    │  ├─ bonjour-service@^1.0.11
    │  ├─ chokidar@^3.5.3
    │  ├─ colorette@^2.0.10
    │  ├─ compression@^1.7.4
    │  ├─ connect-history-api-fallback@^2.0.0
    │  ├─ default-gateway@^6.0.3
    │  ├─ express@^4.17.3
    │  ├─ graceful-fs@^4.2.6
    │  ├─ html-entities@^2.3.2
    │  ├─ http-proxy-middleware@^2.0.3
    │  ├─ ipaddr.js@^2.0.1
    │  ├─ open@^8.0.9
    │  ├─ p-retry@^4.5.0
    │  ├─ rimraf@^3.0.2
    │  ├─ schema-utils@^4.0.0
    │  ├─ selfsigned@^2.1.1
    │  ├─ serve-index@^1.9.1
    │  ├─ sockjs@^0.3.24
    │  ├─ spdy@^4.0.2
    │  ├─ webpack-dev-middleware@^5.3.1
    │  └─ ws@^8.4.2

├─ webpack-dev-middleware@5.3.3
│  ├─ colorette@^2.0.10
│  ├─ memfs@^3.4.3
│  ├─ mime-db@1.52.0
│  ├─ mime-types@^2.1.31
│  ├─ mime-types@2.1.35
│  │  └─ mime-db@1.52.0
│  ├─ range-parser@^1.2.1
│  └─ schema-utils@^4.0.0

package.json
{
  "name": "ai-reviewer-admin",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^13.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix .",
    "coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll=false"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "mq-polyfill": "^1.1.8",
    "prettier": "2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.44.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/EnvConfig.js",
      "!src/**/test-data.js",
      "!src/domain/authentication/*.js"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "nth-check": "^2.0.1"
 }    
}

